# Adjusting scales in a barh "tornado" chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I'm using a tornado plot (essentially a horizontal bar) to plot responses by gender. How do I make the x axis on each side to have the same scale? As you can see from the pic, the right scale goes up to +20, whereas the left one goes up to 10, how do I change that? here's my code:

```py
Concerns = df_Q3['Concerns']
num_concerns = len(Concerns)
Female = df_Q3['Female']
Male = df_Q3['Male']
pos = np.arange(num_concerns) + .5

fig, (ax_left, ax_right) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax_left.barh(pos, Male, align='center', facecolor='cornflowerblue')
ax_left.set_yticks([])
ax_left.invert_xaxis()
ax_right.barh(pos, Female, align='center', facecolor='red')
ax_right.set_yticks(pos)
ax_right.set_yticklabels(Concerns, ha='center', x=+1.5)
plt.suptitle('Main Concerns about return to workplace?')
plt.show()
```

[image: tornado_chart]

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```py
ax_right.set_xlim((0,25))
ax_left.set_xlim((0,25))
```